# How to clear an ArrayList without affecting next funciton?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to read a file and pass it to a class called "Allabaque" that has a String and two List. When I have finished reading the first abaque I want to clear the two Lists so I can get the nexts values but if I clear the List, even if I do it after adding the new abaque, the function passes me the new abaque with the two empty Lists. Here is the code:

```
public void importFrom(String filename) {
    try (
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));) {
        String line;
        String line2;
        int c = 0;
        List<String> Pression = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> Couple = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> P2 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> C2 = new ArrayList<>();
        String Cle = "null";

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            if (c == 2 && !"|".equals(line)) {

                String[] arg = line.split("-");
                boolean u = Pression.add(arg[0]);
                boolean u2 = Couple.add(arg[1]);
            }
            if (c == 1) {
                Cle = line;
                c = 2;
                //System.out.printf("%s",Cle);
            }
            if ("|".equals(line)) {
                c = 1;
                if (!"null".equals(Cle)) {
                    //P2 = Pression;
                    //C2 = Couple;
                    addAbaque(new Abaque(Cle, Pression, Couple));//addAbaque(new Abaque(Cle,P2,C2));
                    Couple.clear();
                    Pression.clear();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.printf("Erreur import");
    }
}
```

The addAbaque method is the simple

```
public void addAbaque(Abaque abaque) {
    mAbaques.add(abaque);``
}
```

Using the debug I think I have found that it's a problem with the memory but I reaaly dont know how to fix it.

I've tried also with two intermedieries List, I putted it like comments, but still nothing.

Comment: the try is like that **try {** not like that **try (**

Comment: @YoucefLaidani OP is using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: ooh this is the first time i see this kind of **try (** i should to learn about that, thank you @Andy Turner

Comment: You should probably specify what "still nothing" means exactly here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearing the `Couple` and `Pression` lists also clears the lists previously passed to the `Abaque` constructor, since you are passing `List` references to the constructor, not copies of the lists.

You can either pass new Lists to the constructor :

```
addAbaque(new Abaque(Cle,new ArrayList<String>(Pression),new ArrayList<String>(Couple)));
```

Or create new Lists instead of clearing the old ones, i.e. replace

```
Couple.clear();
Pression.clear();
```

with

```
Couple = new ArrayList<>();
Pression = new ArrayList<>();
```

The latter alternative is probably more efficient, since you don't have to copy the contents of the original Lists to new Lists, and you don't have to clear any Lists.

Comment: Or take defensive copies in the constructor of `Abaque`.

Comment: @AndyTurner That would also work, but I think avoiding copies (either being passed to the constructor or created within the constructor) would be more efficient. Of course this would only make a difference if the Lists are very large and/or the loop has many iterations.

Comment: it's more efficient, but it places the burden on the client to remember to pass in a defensive copy. Any invariants established in the constructor based upon the contents of the list can easily be invalidated if it is the client's responsibility (assuming there are any such invariants). To quote Bloch, "You must program defensively, with the assumption that
clients of your class will do their best to destroy its invariants.".